# What does this mean? typedef uint64_t uint64_t;

Tags: c++, typedef

What is the meaning of:

```
typedef uint64_t uint64_t;
```

I found it in plain source code, not preprocessed one, in the global namespace. Could it simply be a placeholder in case other types should be used in the future?

Comment: Difficult to say without any context, please post a [mre]

Comment: *In a given non-class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.* (from the C++17 Draft Standard). No idea what that actually ***means*** though.

Comment: It is a legal construct -- see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.typedef#3. It's unclear why somebody would do that.

Comment: There is no meaning to this. There are 1001 possible explanations why this line of code exists, but it is useless.

Comment: @Drew I've chosen the 2nd. There's a good explanation why one might want to do this: Prevent valid inclusion of that header in c code, so _does nothing_ isn't entirely true.

Comment: @DrewDormann Besides what πάντα ῥεῖ said, it does define a type name, so "does nothing" isn't accurate. Consider that this definition may be in a different namespace than where the other `uint64_t` is defined.

Comment: Was it by any chance enclosed in a namespace? It would be a valid way to pull an equivalent definition from an outer scope into an inner scope. That's how those aliases may be put into the `std` namespace by `cstdint`, for example.

Comment: I'm reopening the question. While additional details could be provided, such as the context in which this code was seen, the code is valid, and the question is answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef` has the same scope as regular variables in C/C++.

So, it is scoped. In each scope, we could define a new meaning. But, if it has a meaning in that scopy, it cannot be redefined. Also not with the scope operator `::`

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    {
        typedef uint64_t unit64_t;
        std::cout << typeid(uint64_t).name() << '\n';
    }
    {
        typedef char uint64_t;
        std::cout << typeid(uint64_t).name() << '\n';

        typedef uint64_t unit64_t;  // Still a char
        std::cout << typeid(uint64_t).name() << '\n';

        // typedef ::uint64_t unit64_t; // Error
        // std::cout << typeid(uint64_t).name() << '\n';
    }
    {
        typedef uint64_t unit64_t;
        std::cout << typeid(uint64_t).name() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, I tend to say, that is has no meaning and is a rather academic question.

But I am nearly sure that somebody may find a use case.

Answer (score -1):

typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

the original definition of `uint64_t` is `unsigned long long`, if that's what you were trying to figure out? It's type is defined in the `stdint.h` header

Comment: I think the OP is confused by the fact that the code in their question defines a type that is *itself*. That is, defining a `uint64_t` as a `uint64_t`. I'm not sure you answer really addresses why code like that is used.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33969439)